# require() of ES Module not supported in built electron app code

Tags: angular, electron, nrwl-nx

As a result of a recent attempt to upgrade my angular-electron-NX monorepo to the latest versions of Angular, NX and Electron (16, 16 and 26 respectively), I run into problems when running the electron service.
One thing worth noting is that I am using version 16.0.0-beta.1 of nx-electron, as this is the most up to date one available, and NX-electron is used as the executor in both the build and the serve target of the app in question.
Error when attempting to serve the app:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/blank/git/myrepo/gui-js/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /home/blank/git/myrepo/gui-js/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13327)
    at @angular/core (/home/blank/git/myrepo/gui-js/dist/apps/minsky-electron/main.js:7522:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/blank/git/myrepo/gui-js/dist/apps/minsky-electron/main.js:7700:41)
    at ./libs/shared/src/lib/material/material.module.ts (/home/blank/git/myrepo/gui-js/dist/apps/minsky-electron/main.js:7405:71)
```

The line number is referring to the first of these require statements at the bottom of the main.js file, which seem out of place in a file built from TS with an ES module target:

```
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = require("@angular/core");

/***/ }),
```

above these lines, `__webpack_require__` is usually used without causing errors. Target and module are both set to ES2022 in the app's tsconfig file. What else can I manipulate to prevent my build process from producing these illegal require statements? Is there any code in nx-electron 16.0.0-beta.1 responsible for this error? If prevention is impossible, is there some way to inject an intermediate script into the pipeline to fix these statements before the file is executed? I am pretty out of my depth on this so feel free to explain anything including the basics and I will gladly provide more details upon request. Github repo and branch can be found here; the relevant code is in the gui-js folder: https://github.com/Rdmkr/minsky/tree/feature/angularUpgrade